# How to form three different classes based on scores of two different columns, can someone guide me, please refer my code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- if ios_score > 0.5 and android_score < 0.5, group them as "iOS user" in output column.
- if ios_score < 0.5 and android_score > 0.5, group them as "Android user" in output column.
- if ios_score > 0.5 and android_score > 0.5, group them as "iOS + Android user" in output column.

I tried using below code, but I get TypeError,

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

```
scores_df.sample(5)

O/P

names   ios_score   android_score  Output

A1       0.428571   0.571429         ?

A2       0.541667   0.708333         ?  

A3       0.333333   0.485714         ?

scores_df.loc[(scores_df['ios_score'] > 0.5 & scores_df['android_score'] < 0.5 ), 'output'] = "iOS" 
scores_df.loc[(scores_df['ios_score'] < 0.5 & scores_df['android_score'] > 0.5 ), 'output'] = "Android"
scores_df.loc[(scores_df['ios_score'] > 0.5 & scores_df['android_score'] > 0.5 ), 'output'] = "iOS + Android"
scores_df.head()
```

Comment: I believe you are missing parentheses as & has a higher precedence than < or >, so try `... ( (scores_df['ios_score'] > 0.5) & (scores_df['android_score'] < 0.5) )`

Comment: @piterbarg yeah you are correct, after adding parentheses, its working fine. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `np.select` you can specify a list of conditions to check, and a list of values to output if respective condition is matched:

```
df['Output'] = np.select([
        ((df['ios_score'] > 0.5) & (df['android_score'] > 0.5)),
        (df['ios_score'] > 0.5),
        (df['android_score'] > 0.5)],
    ['iOS + Android', 'iOS', 'Android'], default='Other')

df
```

Output:

```
  names  ios_score  android_score         Output
0    A1   0.428571       0.571429        Android
1    A2   0.541667       0.708333  iOS + Android
2    A3   0.333333       0.485714          Other
```

Comment: This works! np.select option is really interesting, thank you very much for sharing this.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that it helped!